# How to create ASP.NET project from scratch with older version of Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I'm following some online tutorial to create ASP.NET API 2 project, but the tutorial is a bit old (2015), and it used VS2013 + EntityFramework 5.

My version of project (VS2013 + .Net 4.5.2 + EF 6.1.1(by default)) can be built. But when running, it throws below exception.

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXX' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"
```

After examined, it may be because the base ASP.NET Project uses EF6 while some nuget packages in my project refer to EF5 *(unfortunately these packages seem don't have newer version to use EF6)*.
Therefore 2 versions of EF dlls are used within same project, which throws the captioned exception.

**My question is:**
How can I create ASP.NET project (eg: API 2 project) from scratch with older version of Entity Framework?

I can't find any related opinion when I create ASP.NET using Visual Studio's wizard

**Edited:**
below is my steps:
(File -> New -> Project -> ASP.NET Web Application -> choose WebAPI + check(tick) "MVC" & "Web API" under "Add folders and core references for:" -> OK).

Then I found EntityFramework.dll (ver 6) and EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll (ver 6) are added in References of the newly created project.

Comment: EF isn't part of ASP.NET. You have to add it explicitly, which means you can add whatever version you want. EF 5 thoug is **very** old. And even .NET 4.5.2 reaches end-of-life in April 2022. Upgrade the projects and ditch the obsolete NuGet packages. You'll have to do that very soon anyway

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Many ths for quick reply.  I found the EF is automatically added to my project without asking me which version I want., after I click OK of Add Project wizard.  And I edited my ques, pls refer to "Edited" part for details.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that EF isn't part of ASP.NET. The template you used contains many different NuGet packages, one of which is EF 6. EF 6 was released in 2013, along with VS 2013, which is why it's used by default in that template. Again, you really, really need to update the projects and ditch any NuGet packages that require EF 5. This isn't an `in an ideal world` situation. VS 2013 is 8 years old but obviously, you're using an even older project. It may not be compatible *at all* with the ASP.NET version used by VS 2013. Even if you change the EF version, the rest may fail

Comment: In any case, you can change the EF version from the NuGet package manager.